# Scrape specific rows across multiple tables on Wikipedia

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and am trying scrape election results from this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_2019_New_South_Wales_state_election_(Legislative_Assembly)

Specifically, I'd like to extract Two-Party Preferred results across all districts into the following table format:

```
| District | Party | Candidate | Votes | Percent | Pct_Change|
|----------|-------|-----------|-------|---------|-----------|
|District1 |Party1 |Candidate1 | 28258 | 65.98   | +2.75     |
|District1 |Party2 |Candidate2 | 14572 | 34.02   | -2.75     |
|District2 |...    |...        | ...   | ...     | ...       |
```

The problem is that the rows containing Two-Party Preferred (TPP) results are in the same table as rows containing First Preference results ([see table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmSaD.png)) and the rows share the same class attributes.

So far I'm only able to extract all the rows data for all the districts (except the district names) using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_2019_New_South_Wales_state_election_(Legislative_Assembly)'
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

df = []

for row in soup.find_all('tr', {"class":"vcard"}):
    data = [d.text.rstrip() for d in row.find_all('td')]
    df.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=[' ','Party','Candidate','Votes','Pct','Pct_ch'])
```

My questions are:

1. How can I selectively scrape only the TPP rows, and
2. How can I append the district in the first column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving this would be like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

big_df = pd.DataFrame()

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_2019_New_South_Wales_state_election_(Legislative_Assembly)'

soup = bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
locations = soup.select('h3 span[class="mw-headline"]')
for l in locations:
    df = pd.read_html(str(l.find_next('table')))[0]
    two_party_header = df.index.get_loc(df[df['Party'] == 'Two-party-preferred result'].index[0])
    two_party_df = df.iloc[two_party_header + 1: two_party_header + 3]
    two_party_df.is_copy = False
    two_party_df['Party'] = two_party_df['Party'].map({np.nan: l.text})
    two_party_df.columns = ['Location', 'Party', 'Candidate', 'Votes','%', '±%']
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, two_party_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    
print(big_df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Location    Party   Candidate   Votes   %   ±%
0   Albury  Liberal Justin Clancy   28258   65.98   +2.75
1   Albury  Labor   Lauriston Muirhead  14572   34.02   −2.75
2   Auburn  Labor   Lynda Voltz 24419   59.13   +3.20
3   Auburn  Liberal Kyoung Hee (Christina) Kang 16876   40.87   −3.20
4   Ballina Labor   Asren Pugh  23657   54.31   +1.28
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
181 Wollondilly Labor   Jo-Ann Davidson 12988   36.17   +3.46
182 Wollongong  Labor   Paul Scully 31357   71.37   +7.93
183 Wollongong  Liberal Zachary Fitzpatrick 12580   28.63   −7.93
184 Wyong   Labor   David Harris    27296   62.45   +3.72
185 Wyong   Liberal Ying Shu Li-Cantwell    16415   37.55   −3.72
186 rows × 6 columns
```

For pandas documentation, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Also for BeautifulSoup documentation: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Scrape the idea of selecting all `<tr>` tags at once. As you can see on the page, there are too many tables to even count. In fact, not all tables contain the data you want to extract. So that's not a reliable attempt.

What you want to do is to get all tables related to a District. Also, you want specifically all rows related to a TPP (Two-Party Preferred) block.

Before we start scraping any data, let's take a look at the page's HTML. Using any browser, such as Firefox, you can access the site and inspect it's HTML script. This is very important, as you can know first hand what you will be dealing with. The page's script is long, and there are many kinds of elements inside it. But they all follow some kind of pattern at some point.

This is what we want to get from the site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mw-page-base" class="noprint">...</div> <!-- useless -->
    <div id="mw-head-base" class="noprint">...</div> <!-- useless -->
    <div id="content" class="..." role="main">...</div> <!-- your target -->
    <div id="mw-navigation">...</div> <!-- useless -->
    <footer>...</footer> <!-- useless -->
    ... <!-- useless -->
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see there, this is how this page is represented. There are lots of Divs which contains the data we want to select. But there are also undersired Divs, which also contain tables that are not related to the election's result.

Divs like `mw-navigation` are undersired. If we are going to select all tables from the document's body, we will fetch undesired tables. So, let's select the correct Div Element first: `content`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_2019_New_South_Wales_state_election_(Legislative_Assembly)'
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', {'id': 'content'})
```

If take a look at the District tables on the site's HTML script, each District title is a `<span>` text inside a `<h3>` tag. There are 93 `<h3>` tags inside `content`. So, we should select this exact amount of tables from `content`.

If we print: `print(len(content.select('h3')), len(content.select('table')))`, we will get a result of: `93 99`. So, there are 6 tables that are unrelated to the election's result for each District.

The first one is easy. Its the first table that shows up on the page. The Top-Right table. Now, we have 5 unrelated tables left. If you take a serious look after them, you'll spot them inside Divs with these classes: `navbox` and `navbox-styles`. If we remove those Divs from the HTML, we will select all the 93 tables we want.

```
undesired = content.find_all('div', {'class': 'navbox'})
for udiv in undesired:
    udiv.decompose()

undesired = content.find_all('div', {'class': 'navbox-styles'})
for udiv in undesired:
    udiv.decompose()
```

As we now know that the Top-Right table is also an unrelated table, we can add a `-1` to the table selection, and the result of `print(len(content.select('h3')), len(content.select('table'))-1)` should be `93 93`. So we can be confident we selected all the correct tables.

Now comes the fun part where we will scrape the data into the dataframe.

```
tables = content.select('table')
tables.pop(0) # Remove Top-Right table
df = []
titles = content.select('h3')
for i in range(len(tables)):
    h3 = titles[i]
    table = tables[i]

    title = h3.select('span')[0].decode_contents()
    
    for row in table.select('tr'):
        pass
```

But before we continue, we a few problems with how we're implementating this script. We must check for TPP blocks of rows. So not all rows must be selected. We also must check if a row contains a title, and if that title is the TPP title: `<a>Two-party-preferred</a>`.

So we can define our new functions to help us match those rows:

```
def isRowTitle(tr):
    return tr.find('th') # Either returns an object or None

def isRowTPP(tr):
    a = tr.find('th').find('a')

    if (a is not None):
        if (a.decode_contents() == 'Two-party-preferred'):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

By using an `state` variable, we can check if we entered a TPP block. If `state` is 1, it means we're inside a block. If we `break` the loop, it means we left the block.

But there's also another problem: colspans. I don't know if you want to fetch those rows, but looking at the rows with colspans, they seem to be results of the comparision between both candidates, stating who's the winner I guess.

[image: Rows with Colspan]

In order to keep them out of our dataframe, we can create a function to filter them from our selection:

```
def rowHasColspan(tr):
    cells = tr.select('td')

    for cell in cells:
        if (cell.get('colspan') is not None and int(cell.get('colspan')) > 1):
            return True

    return False
```

Now, by putting it all together, we can finally scrape the data:

```
df = []
titles = content.select('h3')
for i in range(len(tables)):
    h3 = titles[i]
    table = tables[i]

    title = h3.select('span')[0].decode_contents()
    state = 2
    for row in table.select('tr'):
        if (state == 2):
            if (isRowTitle(row) and isRowTPP(row)):
                state -= 1
        elif (state == 1):
            if (isRowTitle(row)):
                break
            else:
                if (not rowHasColspan(row)):
                    cells = row.find_all('td')
                    cells.pop(0)
                    data = [d.text.rstrip() for d in cells]
                    data.insert(0, title)
                    df.append(data)
```

---

Here's the entire script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_2019_New_South_Wales_state_election_(Legislative_Assembly)'
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find('div', {'id': 'content'})

undesired = content.find_all('div', {'class': 'navbox'})
for udiv in undesired:
    udiv.decompose()

undesired = content.find_all('div', {'class': 'navbox-styles'})
for udiv in undesired:
    udiv.decompose()

tables = content.select('table')
tables.pop(0) # Remove Top-Right table

def isRowTPP(tr):
    a = tr.find('th').find('a')

    if (a is not None):
        if (a.decode_contents() == 'Two-party-preferred'):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

def isRowTitle(tr):
    return tr.find('th')

def rowHasColspan(tr):
    cells = tr.select('td')

    for cell in cells:
        if (cell.get('colspan') is not None and int(cell.get('colspan')) > 1):
            return True

    return False

df = []
titles = content.select('h3')
for i in range(len(tables)):
    h3 = titles[i]
    table = tables[i]

    title = h3.select('span')[0].decode_contents()
    state = 2
    for row in table.select('tr'):
        if (state == 2):
            if (isRowTitle(row) and isRowTPP(row)):
                state -= 1
        elif (state == 1):
            if (isRowTitle(row)):
                break
            else:
                if (not rowHasColspan(row)):
                    cells = row.find_all('td')
                    cells.pop(0)
                    data = [d.text.rstrip() for d in cells]
                    data.insert(0, title)
                    df.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=[' ','Party','Candidate','Votes','Pct','Pct_ch'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you target the District name headers and store those nodes in a list, you can then loop that list and find the following results tables.Extract from those tables the relevant rows as a dataframe and add in the district name. Combine all these dataframes into one at the end.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_2019_New_South_Wales_state_election_(Legislative_Assembly)')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
districts = [i for i in soup.select('h2:has(#Results_by_district) ~ h3 .mw-headline')]
results= []

for d in districts:
    t = d.find_next('table')
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [[i.text.strip() for i in t.select('tr:has([title="Two-party-preferred vote"]) + tr td')],
        [i.text.strip() for i in t.select('tr:has([title="Two-party-preferred vote"]) + tr + tr td')]]
    , columns = ['District', 'Party','Candidate','Votes','Percent','Pct_Change'])
    df['District'] = d.text
    results.append(df)
    
all_results = pd.concat(results)
print(all_results)
```

Comment: Did you test the code? How about `Wagga Wagga`?

Comment: Thanks.  I did not spot that outlier.